# jquery .append() not working for my html

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a program which appends an input(`type="hidden"`) using jquery, to an html so that when I click the submit button, it passes the value to a php file and I can process it. However, it seems that the hidden type is not really being appended to the html nor it is being passed to the php file. I already used `method="get"` to see the values in the address bar and `print_r` to see the values being catched but there's nothing. To check if my form is actually passing a value, I added a

```
<input type="hidden" name="absent[]" value="testing" />
```

in the HTML and the value got passed but the ones in the jquery aren't.

Here are my files:
jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $("td").click(function(){
 if($(this).hasClass("on"))
 {
    alert("Already marked absent");

 }
else
{

    $(this).addClass("on");
    var currentCellText = $(this).text();
    var temp = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#collect").append("<input type='hidden' name='absent[]' value = '" + temp + "'/>" + currentCellText);
    alert(temp);

 }
  });

$("#clicky").click(function(){
    $("td").removeClass("on");
    $("#collect").text('');
    $("#collect").append("Absentees: <br>")
    alert(temp);
});
});
```

Here is the html part:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connectdb.php';
$classID = $_SESSION['csID'];

$classQry = "SELECT e.csID, c.subjCode, c.section, b.subj_name, e.studentID, CONCAT(s.lname, ', ' , s.fname)name
FROM ENROLLMENT e, CLASS_SCHEDULE c, STUDENT s, SUBJECT b
WHERE e.csID = c.csID
AND c.csID = '" . $classID . "'
AND c.subjCode = b.subjCode
AND e.studentID = s.studentID
ORDER BY e.sort;";

$doClassQry = mysql_query($classQry);

echo "<table id='tableone'>";
    while($x = mysql_fetch_array($doClassQry))
    {
        $subject = $x['subj_name'];
        $subjCode = $x['subjCode'];
        $section = $x['section'];
        $studentArr[] = $x['name'];
        $studentID[] = $x['studentID'];


    }
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr><th colspan = 7>" . "This is your class: " . $subjCode . " " . $section . " : " . $subject . "</th></tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr>";        
    for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($doClassQry); $i++)
    {
        if($i % 7 == 0)
        {               
            echo "</tr><tr><td id = '". $studentID[$i] . " '>" . $studentArr[$i] . "</td>";             
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td id = '". $studentID[$i] . " '>" . $studentArr[$i] . "</td>";
        }

    }
    echo "</tr>";       
    echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Here's the html part with the form:

```
<form name="save" action="saveTest.php" method="post">
<div id="submitt">
    <input type="hidden" name="absent[]" value="testing"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>
</form>
```

And here's the php part which processes the form (saveTest.php):

```
<?php

$absent  = $_POST['absent'];
//echo "absnt" . $absent[] . "<br>";
echo count($absent) . "<br>";
//print_r($_POST) . "<br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is the element with id `collect` inside the form? It needs to be.

```
$("<input type='hidden' name='absent[]' />").val(temp)
                                            .appendTo('form[name="save"]');
$('#collect').append(currentCellText);
```

Comment: WOW I TOTALLY MISSED THAT. The id collect isn't inside the form. Wow really! I've been working with this for hours. Thank you so much for pointing that out. Sorry though, newbie jquery user here :)))))

Comment: And yeah, I used a hidden element because the element only gets appended when I click on the <td>. That way I'm pushing those hidden element's id's to an array which I'll process in the php file. I don't know other ways to pass an array to the php other than using form techniques.

Comment: @user1056998 I see, adding more should be ok as well. I'll update.

Comment: Thanks for updating, it's clearer now. By the way, is there another way for me to put the hidden element's id's in a jquery array allowing me to submit it to a form once the submit button has been clicked? I'm just curious if there's an alternative way so I could learn new techniques. Thanks in advance :))

Comment: I suppose you could keep it in a javascript variable, then serialize it when posting via AJAX.  This way works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly.

```
$("body").delegate("#editorjs_menu_list ul li a", "click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```